# merge multiple files by reading them simultaneously line by line?

Tags: python

I have 3 files:

*file1:*

```
    chrM    6423    5
    chrM    6432    4
    chrM    7575    1
    chrM    7670    1
    chrM    7933    1
    chrM    7984    1
    chrM    8123    1
    chrM    9944    1
    chrM    10434   1
    chrM    10998   13
    chrM    10999   19
    chrM    11024   17
    chrM    11025   29
    chrM    11117   21
    chrM    11118   42
    chr1    197095350   2
chr1    197103061   1
chr1    197103582   1
chr1    197103615   1
chr1    197103810   3
chr1    197103885   2
chr1    197104256   1
chr1    197107467   4
chr1    197107480   5
chr1    197107498   6
chr1    197107528   10
chr1    197107805   1
chr1    197107806   1
chr1    197107813   1
chr1    197107814   1
chr1    197107839   1
chr1    197107840   1
chr1    197107855   1
chr1    197107856   1
chr1    197107877   1
chr1    197107878   1
chr1    197111511   1
chr1    197120122   1
chr1    197125503   1
chr1    197126978   1
chr1    197127070   1
chr1    197127084   1
chr1    197129731   2
chr1    197129758   2
chr1    197129765   1
chr1    197167632   2
chr1    197167652   2
chr1    197167668   2
chr1    197167682   2
chr1    197181417   1
chr1    197181973   3
chr1    197181975   3
chr1    197192150   0
```

*file2:*

```
  chrM  6423    5
    chrM    6432    4
    chrM    6582    1
    chrM    6640    1
    chrM    6643    1
    chrM    7140    1
    chrM    10998   7
    chrM    10999   8
    chrM    11024   10
    chrM    11025   13
    chrM    11117   12
    chrM    11118   33
    chr1    197095157   2
chr1    197095185   2
chr1    197098860   1
chr1    197105061   1
chr1    197107422   1
chr1    197107436   1
chr1    197107467   3
chr1    197107480   4
chr1    197107498   3
chr1    197107528   4
chr1    197107805   2
chr1    197107813   2
chr1    197107839   1
chr1    197108557   1
chr1    197108591   1
chr1    197108596   1
chr1    197108617   1
chr1    197108651   1
chr1    197139308   1
chr1    197139335   1
chr1    197143403   1
chr1    197143442   1
chr1    197145546   1
chr1    197148715   1
chr1    197148723   1
chr1    197148731   1
chr1    197148761   1
chr1    197153190   1
chr1    197166831   1
chr1    197166847   2
chr1    197166922   2
chr1    197166950   1
chr1    197166954   1
chr1    197167041   1
chr1    197167778   1
chr1    197167791   1
chr1    197167834   1
chr1    197167857   2
chr1    197167860   2
chr1    197167865   1
chr1    197167867   1
chr1    197167871   1
chr1    197167935   2
chr1    197167946   2
chr1    197167948   2
chr1    197167951   2
chr1    197167974   1
chr1    197167980   1
chr1    197168142   1
chr1    197168163   1
chr1    197168195   1
chr1    197168210   1
chr1    197169548   1
chr1    197169580   1
chr1    197169609   1
chr1    197183318   1
chr1    197183404   1
chr1    197184910   1
chr1    197184937   1
chr1    197186368   1
chr1    197191991   1
chr1    197192031   1
chr1    197192047   1
chr1    197192097   1
chr1    197192106   1
chr1    197192125   1
chr1    197192150   1
```

*file3:*

```
    chrM    6423    2
    chrM    6432    1
    chrM    6766    1
    chrM    6785    1
    chrM    10075   1
    chrM    10084   1
    chrM    10998   7
    chrM    10999   8
    chrM    11024   7
    chrM    11025   14
    chrM    11117   8
chr1    197095943   1
chr1    197096144   1
chr1    197104061   1
chr1    197104257   1
chr1    197107805   2
chr1    197122470   1
chr1    197123085   1
chr1    197123093   1
chr1    197126978   1
chr1    197142562   1
chr1    197157076   1
chr1    197157101   2
chr1    197162035   4
chr1    197167431   1
chr1    197167470   1
chr1    197167535   1
chr1    197167652   1
chr1    197167668   1
chr1    197167682   1
chr1    197167715   1
chr1    197167734   1
chr1    197167755   1
chr1    197168107   2
chr1    197168113   2
chr1    197172198   1
chr1    197172211   1
chr1    197172221   1
chr1    197172271   1
chr1    197175787   1
chr1    197175806   1
chr1    197175822   1
chr1    197192150   0
```

*resulting file should be like this:*

```
    6423    chrM    2   5   5
    6432    chrM    1   4   4
  6582  chrM    1
197093370   chr1    1
197093385   chr1    1
197094791   chr1    1
197094813   chr1    1
197094855   chr1    1
197094857   chr1    1
197095157   chr1    2
197095185   chr1    2
197095350   chr1    2
197095943   chr1    1
197096
```

Now my code is working properly.But with an issu in while loop that after merging many records nearly at the end of the merged file it stopped writing on the file and just wrote 197096   .... and stopped with an error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 4, in 
IndexError: list index out of range

I think this error is related to while loop.I dont know why its happening.I am also changing me code as u can see below:
Look her comes the problem:u can see clearly in resultant file that in this situation some thing is happening that after reading from single files code is not able to read common values from all files and also at this situation it is not giving 7575 that should come after7140.

I have multiple files that are large and I want to read them all line by line and merge them together if they all have same value for column no.2 for which I used the logic of taking all the 2nd column val in a list and then found the smallest value of them. writing smallest value records (column 3 saved in mycover) from the files showed smallest value to a new file. and then keep the track of files that are read to read next line from them in `my_newfile[]` and deleted the records that have been written to the file.

Hope it will be sufficient to understand. I dont know how to repeat the process until all the files reached their end so to read all the records from all files. My code is as follows:

```
    import sys
import glob
import errno
path = '*Sorted_Coverage.txt'   
filenames = glob.glob(path)  
files = [open(i, "r") for i in filenames]

p=1
mylist=[]
mychr=[]
mycover=[]
new_mychr=[]
new_mycover=[]
new_mylist=[]
myfile=[]
new_myfile=[]
ab=""
g=1
result_f = open('MERGING_water_onlyselected.txt', 'a')
for j in files: 
    line = j.readline()
    parts = line.split()
    mychr.append(parts[0])
    mycover.append(parts[2])
    mylist.append(parts[1])
    myfile.append(j)
mylist=map(int,mylist)
minval = min(mylist)
ind = [i for i, v in enumerate(mylist) if v == minval]
not_ind = [i for i, v in enumerate(mylist) if v != minval]
w=""
j=0
for j in xrange(len(ind)):  # writing  records to file with minimum value
    if(j==0):
        ab = (str(mylist[ind[j]])+'\t'+mychr[ind[j]]+'\t'+mycover[ind[j]])
    else:
        ab=ab+'\t'+mycover[ind[j]]

#smallest written on file

result_f.writelines(ab+'\n')
ab=""

for i in ind:
    new_myfile.append(myfile[i])

      #removing the records by index which have  been used from mylists .
for i in sorted(ind, reverse=True):
    del mylist[i]
    del mycover[i]
    del mychr[i]
    del myfile[i]


#how to iterate the following code from all records of all files till the end of each file
while(True):
    for i in xrange(len(new_myfile)):
        print len(new_myfile)       
        myfile.append(new_myfile[i])
        line = new_myfile[i].readline()
        parts = line.split()
        mychr.append(parts[0])
        mycover.append(parts[2])
        mylist.append(parts[1])
        new_myfile=[]
    mylist=map(int, mylist)
    minval = min(mylist)
    print minval
    print("list values:")
    print mylist
    ind = [i for i, v in enumerate(mylist) if v == minval]
    not_ind = [i for i, v in enumerate(mylist) if v !=  minval]
    k=0
    ab=""
    for j in xrange(len(ind)):  # writing  records to file with minimum value
        if(j==0):
            ab = (str(mylist[ind[j]])+'\t'+str(mychr[ind[j]])+'\t'+str(mycover[ind[j]]))
            k=k+1
        else:
            ab=ab+'\t'+str(mycover[ind[j]])
            k=k+1
    #smallest written on file
    result_f.writelines(ab+'\n')
    ab=""
    for i in ind:
        new_myfile.append(myfile[i])
      #removing the records by index which have  been used from mylists .
    for i in sorted(ind, reverse=True):
        del mylist[i]
        del mycover[i]
        del mychr[i]
        del myfile[i]
result_f.close()
```

I've been searching for a solution for many days but still could not find any. I have no idea whether this code could be improved more or not as I'm quite new to python.

If anyone could be of help I shall be highly grateful.

Comment: Can you clarify a little more and zero in on the part of your code you need help with?

Comment: #how to iterate the following code from all records of all files till the end of each file:i want to add some loop that will iterate the following code upto end again and again until all the records from all the files are read and mergeged to MERGING_TEST3.txt. I give u some example to make it more clear that what i want to do basically:

Comment: file1: chrM 135 18
chrM 229 2
chrM 230 18
chrM 263 3                                                                               file 2:chrM 134 1
chrM 135 11
chrM 229 1
chrM 230 15                                                                             file 3 :chrM 134 2
chrM 135 8
chrM 229 3                                                                  when i will merge these 3 files the result will be like:134 chrM 1 2
135 chrM 18 11 8

Comment: hope it will make it more clear.

Comment: also i want to keep the merging go on if any of the file ends.means repeat the below given code until all the files are read until end

Comment: can u put the content in your comments in the question? Also, add some formatting so that multiple lines in your file can be seen. For now, it seems that file1 has a single line.

Comment: i can even send you my files if u say so and the merged file that i have generated using this code

Comment: Man, the formatting is awful! I'm gonna try to fix it

Comment: I don't understand the examples: 1) there are 2 numbers `11 2` in 1st line of the resulting file, but 3 numbers in 2nd line; 2) the resulting file seems to be too long - there are no entries 645, 646, 685 in the input files.

Comment: soory that was a pasting mistake i dont know why its appearing now as sigle line

Comment: now its ok. yes resulting file will be very big that will include all the entires having single incidence in any of the files. that why i am wrting each line as it  is processed on the file

Comment: I think I see now. You just want to merge the files keeping the entries sorted wrt to the second column, and group the third column if values of the 2nd one repeat. Is it correct? It would be quite easy if files were small (but you mentioned in the other post, they're large).

Comment: yes each is around 3GB

Comment: the code in while loop has some problem cz after some time it starts giving value only from one file and dont read any other files.

Comment: i think in while loop when records from all the files stored in myfile[] are printed on file it gets empty and then it starts reading only the file thats in the new_myfile[] and after it dont read any other file.how to solve that.

Comment: is there any way out

Comment: I think you may need a priority queue for this to work. I'll try to write some code later.

Comment: thanks.i will be highly obliged if that could run properly on my huge files.

Comment: @Ahsan  I already wrote an answer but if you are interested here is a comment on your code. You are manipulating `myfiles` and `new_myfiles`  and then probably accessing one of them with a wrong index `i`. This raises an exception (index out of range), and consequently, the write buffer is nut flushed to the output file. Hence the broken output in the last line. As for the skipped entries (e.g. missing 7575), it's either something related (indices not pointing to where they should) or the algorithm is flawed (really hard to tell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Basic solution

This is quite a simple approach. I don't know how it may perform on large files (see my comments below).

I assume that all files are already **sorted with respect to the second column**. Also, I assume that the first column signatures ('chrM', 'chr1') remains the same for a fixed value in the 2nd column (I'll call this column 'id' below).

The algorithm is straightforward:

1. read one line from each file (I call read lines 'items')
2. choose one 'item' with the smallest 'id' (any one) and compare it with 'current_item':

   if both have the same id: combine them
   else: write 'current_item' to file and replace it with 'item'
3. read one line from the same file as 'item' was read (if any lines left)
4. repeat from 1. until all lines from all files are read.

---

```
import glob
import numpy as np

path = './file[0-9]*'
filenames = glob.glob(path) 
files = [open(i, "r") for i in filenames] 
output_file = open('output_file', mode = 'a')

# last_ids[i] = last id number read from files[i]
# I choose np.array because of function np.argmin
last_ids = np.ones(shape = len(files)) * np.inf
last_items = [None] *len(files)

# Note: When we hit EOF in a file, the corresponding entries from "files", "last_items", and "last_ids" will be deleted

for i in range(len(files)):
    line = files[i].readline()
    if line:
        item = line.strip().split()
        last_ids[i] = int(item[1])
        last_items[i] = item

# Find an item with the smallest id 
pos = np.argmin(last_ids)
current_item = last_items[pos]
# Inverting positions, so that id is first
current_item[0], current_item[1] = current_item[1], current_item[0]  

while True:    
    # Read next item from the corresponding file
    line = files[pos].readline()
    if line:
        item = line.strip().split()
        last_ids[pos] = int(item[1])
        last_items[pos] = item
    else:
        # EOF in files[pos], so delete it from the lists
        files[pos].close()
        del(files[pos])
        del(last_items[pos])
        last_ids = np.delete(last_ids, pos)
        if last_ids.size == 0:
            # No more files to read from
            break 

    # Find an item with the smallest id 
    pos = np.argmin(last_ids)
    if last_items[pos][1] == current_item[0]:
        # combine:
        current_item.append(last_items[pos][2])
    else:
        # write current to file and replace:
        output_file.write(' '.join(current_item) + '\n')
        current_item = last_items[pos]
        current_item[0], current_item[1] = current_item[1], current_item[0]  

# The last item to write:
output_file.write(' '.join(current_item) + '\n')
output_file.close()
```

### Small files solution:

If all files were small enough to fit into memory, then the following code is definitely shorter. Whether it's faster may depend on the data. (See comments below.)

```
import glob 
import pandas as pd

path = './file[0-9]*'    
filenames = glob.glob(path) 

df_list = []
# Read in all files and concatenate to a single data frame:
for file in filenames:
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file, header = None, sep = '\s+'))    
df = pd.concat(df_list)

# changing type for convenience:
df[2] = df[2].astype(str)
# sorting here is not necessary:
# df = df.sort_values(by = 1)

df2 = df.groupby(by = 1).aggregate({0:'first', 2: lambda x: ' '.join(x)})
df2.to_csv('output_file', header = None)
# (Columns in 'output_file' are separated by commas. )
```

### Comments

I tested both solutions on several input files with 1000-10000 lines. Usually the basic solutions is faster (sometimes twice as fast as the other one). But it depends on the structure of data. If there are many repeating 'id's, then pandas might be slightly more advantageous (by quite a small margin).

I think the both approaches can be combined with the use of `pd.read_csv` with options `chunksize` or `iterator`. That way we could read in and operate on larger chunks of data (not single lines). But I'm not sure now if it leads to a much faster code.

If it fails (and if nobody finds a better way), you may consider running a map reduce algorithm on Amazon Web Services. There's some work to fix all settings at the beginning but a map-reduce algorithm is very straightforward for this kind of problems.

Comment: thanks alot. this worked v.well.I am highly obliged.u solved it.thanks